# COM interop - event and property with same name

Tags: c#, com-interop

I have an old COM object implemented in C++/ATL. The object has an event and a property with the same name. This is not a problem in COM.

In C#, the property effectively hides the event, so it doesn't seem possible to add an event handler.

Is there a solution to this problem in C#?

(Interestingly, you can handle it in VB.NET using the WithEvents and Handles mechanism, but that doesn't help me in C#).

---

**Update**

This is the definition of the event interface (IDL).

```
// Event interface to be implemented by channel objects.
[
  uuid(FF34BE60-C584-4f45-B3A1-231F0E08BE83),
  helpstring("IChannelEvents Interface"),
]
dispinterface IChannelEvents
{
  properties:
  methods:
  [id(1), helpstring("")]
  void OnlineValue ( [in] double        dValue,
                     [in] double        dMax,
                     [in] double        dMin,
                     [in] BSTR          Unit,
                     [in] VARIANT_BOOL  bOverloaded );

  [id(2), helpstring("")]
  void MeasuredExcitation ( [in] double        dValue,
                            [in] VARIANT_BOOL  bValueValid,
                            [in] VARIANT_BOOL  bInRange );

  [id(3), helpstring("")]
  void MultipleOnlineValues ( [in] VARIANT        Values,
                              [in] BSTR           Unit );
} ;
```

This it the definition of the COM object (IDL)

```
[
  uuid(2B725FC4-6FE6-4D53-9528-F098F04E98EE),
  helpstring("Channel Class")
]
coclass Channel
{
  [default] interface IChannel;
  [default, source ] dispinterface IChannelEvents ;
};
```

The interface IChannel contains a property named OnlineValue. I don't think the exact definition is important.

Hans seems to be suggesting something like this:

```
class EventTest
{
  void Test()
  {
    Channel         c  = null ;
    IChannelEvents  ce = c as IChannelEvents ;
    ce.OnlineValue += this.OnlineValue ;
  }

  void OnlineValue ( double        dValue,
                     double        dMax,
                     double        dMin,
                     string        Unit,
                     bool          bOverloaded )
  {
  }
}
```

This generates the error

```
Error CS1656    
Cannot assign to 'OnlineValue' because it is a 'method group'
```

This code doesn't really make sense to me, because - as Hans says - the channel object does not implements the event interface, so why would the cast from Channel to IChannelEvents work?

Comment: Don't usually advocate this, but I'd see if you could run the VB code through a translator to C# and see if that does the trick. Since both languages ultimately create IL, you ***should*** be able to handle the situation in C#.

Comment: The COM object should implement two COM interfaces, like for example `IStuff` and `_IStuffEvents_Event` (the dispinterface one). You can avoid the ambiguity if you cast the COM instance using these interfaces.

Comment: Certainly there is an event interface. It is defined in IDL as a source interface. I can't cast the object directly to that interface (because it doesn't implement it). I would need to cast it to some other object with the same source interface, but without the 'normal' interface. I do not know any way to do that.

Comment: It is up to the client code to implement the interface so it can get the event callbacks.  Which in the case of C# is done by the CLR, it creates an RCW to wrap the object.  The CLR supports a cast to obtain a reference to the event interface it implements.  If you haven't tried it then you need to try it, if it "doesn't work" then you need to at least show us repro code.

Comment: Thanks @HansPassant. I have edited the question. At present, I don't understand how that would work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found a solution, which is probably what Hans Passant was suggesting.

The event interface is named IChannelEvents. The type library importer generates an interface named IChannelEvents_Event.

Disassembled, the interface definition is as follows:

```
[ComEventInterface(typeof(IChannelEvents), typeof(IChannelEvents_EventProvider)), ComVisible(false), TypeLibType(16)]
public interface IChannelEvents_Event
{
  event IChannelEvents_OnlineValueEventHandler OnlineValue;
  event IChannelEvents_MeasuredExcitationEventHandler MeasuredExcitation;
  event IChannelEvents_MultipleOnlineValuesEventHandler MultipleOnlineValues;
}
```

I can cast the COM object to this interface and add an event handler as shown below.

```
class EventTest
{
  void Test()
  {
    Channel              c  = null ;
    IChannelEvents_Event ee = c as IChannelEvents_Event ;

    ee.OnlineValue += OnlineValue ;
  }

  void OnlineValue ( double        dValue,
                     double        dMax,
                     double        dMin,
                     string        Unit,
                     bool          bOverloaded )
  {
  }
}
```

This interface does not show up in intellisense, but after entering it, visual Studio sets the text color to indicate that it recognizes the type.